# How to determine the file name involved in an IO operation using windows etw tracing?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, etw

I am trying to create a consumer application in  `vc++`, which will collect all disk events using etw tracing at real-time.

I have enabled two flags, the  `EVENT_TRACE_FLAG_DISK_FILE_IO` and the `EVENT_TRACE_FLAG_DISK_IO` for tracing but the problem is I am not getting as many FileIO_Name events compared to the number of `DiskIo_TypeGroup1` events.

But If I only enable the `EVENT_TRACE_FLAG_DISK_FILE_IO`  flag then I am getting more number of `FileIO_Name` events in my calllback.

```
FLAG                                          EVENT

EVENT_TRACE_FLAG_DISK_IO                      Enables the following DiskIo event types:
0x00000100                                     DiskIo_TypeGroup1
                                               DiskIo_TypeGroup3

EVENT_TRACE_FLAG_DISK_FILE_IO                 Enables the following FileIo event type:
0x00000200                                    FileIo_Name
```

I guess I need both the flags because... from the **FileIO_Name** events I will get `FileObject` and `FileName`  data and from **DiskIO_TypeGroup1**  I will get FileObject , `DiskNumber` , TransferSize and other data's I need to match the common `fileobjects` to merge both separate data set and get the desired output.

so when I use both flags I get the `DiskIO_TypeGroup1:FileObject` ratio as **4:1**.
But when I tweet my code to get only the `FileIO_Name` event I get 3x times the events that I was getting earlier, if not more.

Comment: how large is your buffersize? Try to increase it.

Comment: Thanks , for your reply... I have my buffersize as 1 MB since that was the maximum buffersize that can be allocated.

Comment: The thing that puzzles me is how does windows resource monitor , in its Disk Activity (under Disk Tab) shows the FileName along with other details like the Process Name , Process Id , Bytes Read or written etc.And these list gets populated almost instantly. 
Cause the way I am doing it the I am hardly finding a file-Name with a fileObject that matches with the DiskIo_TypeGroup1 events...

Oh and I know that resource monitor is using etw to get data's, so taking that as a reference.

Comment: take a look at the ExtendedTools plugin of ProcessHacker, it implements this data gathering: http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/etwmon_8c_source.html, http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/etwstat_8c_source.html

Comment: @magicandre ...Hi Thanks again for the links. Now I guess I am getting more number of common fileobjects from both the DiskIO_TypeGroup1 and FileIo_Name events. 
But here's 
Issue no 1- I see that I only get common file objects for DiskIO_TypeGroupI event Type =11 that is for disk write.
for Disk reads (event type =10)I am not getting any common file objects.

Issue 2- 
Also noticed  that I am only recieving  FileIO_Name events "FileCreate" and "FileDelete". But "FileRunDown" and "Name" events are not coming up.

Comment: Hi, I can associate now the filenames from the FileIO_Name events with the DiskIO_TypeGroup1 events, actually I was losing events since my events rate of events consumtion was slower than the rate @ which I was bomberded with events.....