# Correlate ETW file object with DiskIO events

Tags: c++, etw

I am trying to understand how to make ETW tracing work reliably.  The problem I am having is that I do not consistently receive the FileIo rundown or name events that I need in order to correlate file names with DiskIo events at the driver level.  I am using realtime event tracing.  I have studied the statistics coming back from ETW at the end of a session and I do not appear to be dropping events (EventsLost and RealTimeBuffersLost are always zero).  In some cases, I receive the FileName/FileRundown events and in others I do not.

I have found some useful information in this thread: [How to determine the file name involved in an IO operation using windows etw tracing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27813110/how-to-determine-the-file-name-involved-in-an-io-operation-using-windows-etw-tra).  There I found some links to the source code for ProcessHacker (http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/etwmon_8c_source.html).  Studying the ProcessHacker code, I see a couple of differences with how I am setting up event tracing.  I wonder if these differences are leading to my issues?

First, ProcessHacker sets up two trace sessions.  One receives the bulk of the desired ETW events (FileIo, DiskIo, NetworkIo).  The other only looks for FileRundown events.  In my application, I use one trace session to catch everything.  An interesting thing I notice about the EVENT_TRACE_PROPERTIES used for the rundown session is that it does not specify any EnableFlags.  The "main" session uses the flags that I would expect (DISK_IO, FILE_IO, NETWORK_TCPIP).

Second, ProcessHacker uses the newer "EventRecord" callback instead of the old "EventTrace" callbacks.  My app is using the "old" EventTrace callback.  This selection is made by specifying PROCESS_TRACE_MODE_EVENT_RECORD in the EVENT_TRACE_LOGFILE structure.

Would either of these differences lead to the behavior I am seeing?

Answer (score 2):

I answered my own question.  The key was the first difference I pointed out.  I split the event handling tasks between two threads instead of trying to handle everything in a single thread.  So, now I direct FileIo, DiskIo and Image events to one thread and FileCreate, FileRundown and FileName events to another.  This solved the issue.

This suggests that I was dropping ETW events somewhere along the chain.  Yet the ETW session statistics do not report this fact (EventsLost RealTimeEventsLost and BuffersLost are all zero).

I guess it should be obvious, but performance is critical when trying to process large volumes (millions) of ETW events.  In my case, I am listening to the events at the Driver level (DriverCall, DriverComplete, etc.).  This ramps up the volume of events and seems to exacerbate the issue I was seeing.

I ran some simple experiments before resolving this.  In the experiment, I disabled the Driver level events.  In this case, a single threaded event processor was able to keep up with the DiskIo events and the FileName events.  As soon as I turn the Driver events back on I get back to the state where I do not reliably receive FileName events.